# Mongodb find document with too large key

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to create an index and I'm getting this error:

> 2018-12-30T15:28:30.853-0800 I COMMAND  [conn580067] command db.$cmd
>   command: createIndexes { createIndexes: "node", indexes: [ {
>   background: true, sparse: true, key: { type: 1, players: 1, ct: 1,
>   image: 1, domain: 1 }, name: "browse" } ], writeConcern: {} }
>   exception: WiredTigerIndex::insert: key too large to index, failing 
>   5813 { : "card", : null, : 1390347921368.0, :
>   "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBxISEBIUEhQVFhQQEBAQDxAVFA8UFBUQFBQWFxQRFBQYHCggGBolHBQUITEhJSkrLi4uFx8zODMsNygtLisBCgoKDg0NFBAQFywcHBwsLCwsLCwsLC...",
>   : null } code:17280 numYields:3312 reslen:354 locks:{ Global: {
>   acquireCount: { r: 3313, w: 3313 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w:
>   3313, W: 2 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 3313 } }, Metadata: {
>   acquireCount: { W: 1 } } } protocol:op_query 8206ms

How do I figure out which document it is so that I can delete it?

mongod version: 3.4.11 (WiredTiger)

Comment: What is the MongoDB version(x,y,z)?

Comment: @MdHaidarAliKhan mongod version: 3.4.11 (WiredTiger)

Comment: The total BSON size and fields in the offending key are included in the error message. It looks like this key would have been 5813 bytes and most of the fields are null. The `image` field includes a binary JPEG image which is probably both unhelpful to index and the main cause of excessive key length. Creating the index definition without `image` would probably work unless other fields include very long values.

Comment: A [sparse compound index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-sparse/#sparse-compound-indexes) is also probably not going to do what you expect: an index entry will be created as long as the document contains at least one of the keys, but this index may not be useful depending on your queries. Sparse indexes will not be selected where doing so could result in an [incomplete result set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-sparse/#sparse-index-and-incomplete-results) for queries and sort operations. It would be worth reviewing explain results in a development/staging environment.

Comment: @Stennie I found the first entry in the question and now I'm looking at the same error for other documents. It is an error that images contain image data. The image fields normally contain urls to images. As it is, I would just like an easy way to delete the documents that are offending. The only results I want from this index are on documents that have all the fields, so the document above would indeed not be something I want returned. I would like to delete it.

Comment: If you have an expected pattern for your `image` fields you can use a regular expression to find values that don't start with the expected string value(s). For example, if the image urls should start with http(s), you could use: `db.myCollection.find({image: { $not: /^http/ }}, { _id: 1 })` to print the `_id`s for suspect values.